# How to pinpoint Amazon S3 keeping phone active 48+ hrs?

Tags: ios, battery, ipados, screen-time

On my iPad, I noticed in my Screen Time dashboard that “s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com” has been active for 48+ continuous hours. During that period, my iPad has most certainly had the screen turned off.

How can I determine the source of this usage?

[image: Screentime 24hr]

[image: screentime weekly]